# Center TabContext material-ui/core

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a `TabContext` like so:

```js
<TabContext value={selectedTab.toString()}>
  <TabList>
   <Tab>Hi</Tab>
   <Tab>Hi2</Tab>
  </TabList>
</TabContext>
```

However, all the tabs are aligned to the right, I want to align them to the center. With the `Tabs` object, I can just pass the `centered` attribute, however, it doesn't work the same with the `TabContext`.

How can I center the `TabContext` like how we do with the `Tabs`?

Comment: from the [TabList documentation](https://mui.com/api/tab-list/) it's written `Props of the Tabs component are also available`. So you can write `<TabList centered>`

Comment: Oh! Odd that we can do it for the tablist and not the tabcontext. Would you like to post this as the answer and I'll mark it as correct?

Comment: yes, I just posted the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [TabList documentation](https://mui.com/api/tab-list/) => `Props of the Tabs component are also available`

So you can write :

```
<TabList centered>
  <Tab>Hi</Tab>
  <Tab>Hi2</Tab>
</TabList>
```